# Kotlin Android App array is not getting pushed to API using retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, post, retrofit2

I am trying to create a Kotlin based Android app which uses the Retrofit library to save an Array to server and then whatever results it fetches I need to put in a RecyclerView. I have already done creating the code for only @GET request which does give me data in JSON. But now I want to test with @POST where i will pass some data to the API and API will return the the older @GET data which I retrieved in previous step. This is to unify my API calling and App will just hit 1 API that can work as PUSH api and PULL api too.

So, I have written the following code to POST an array in Kotlin (Android Studio), where the return data of POST is being shown correctly in my RecyclerView Items, but the POST call is not saving the POST data sent from the APP. Any suggestions please?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
private fun saveAndFetchItemsFromServer() {
    refreshLayout.isRefreshing = true
    
    ItemsApi().saveData(myFunction()).enqueue(object : Callback<List<SingleItem>> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<SingleItem>>, t: Throwable) {
            refreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<SingleItem>>,
            response: Response<List<SingleItem>>
        ) {
            refreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
            val items = response.body()
            
            items?.let {
                showItems(it)
            }
        }
        
    })
}

private fun myFunction():Array<String> {
    var arrayValues = arrayOf("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")
    
    return arrayValues;
}
```

**ItemsApi.kt**:

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.POST

const val BASE_URL = "https://www.myownurl.com/"

interface ItemsApi {
    // GET Request is Working Fine
    //  @GET("/getData")
    //  fun getItems(): Call<List<SingleItem>>
    
    // The return data of POST is being shown correctly 
    // but Server is not getting the array sent from the APP
    @POST("/saveAndGetData")
    fun saveData(@Body newData:Array<String>):Call<List<SingleItem>>
    
    companion object {
        
        operator fun invoke() : ItemsApi{
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl((BASE_URL))
                .addConverterFactory((GsonConverterFactory.create()))
                .build()
                .create(ItemsApi::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving something on your OnResponseMethod?, can you log it and post the response in your answer? post the code of the myFunction() function. I imagine that function gets the Array to be sent with the POST method.

Comment: Response is working perfectly fine. Only issue is the array is not being sent to server which I have created inside myFunction(). Updated the code of this function now. It is actually just a simple function which is returning array.

Comment: Try using ArrayList instead of array. It seems to work better when using it in a @Body in retrofit. Let me know if it works so I can post it as an Answer :)

Comment: sorry, I didn't get luck even after changing that to ArrayList. Still I am finding error in my code that which portion i should correct within.

Comment: why do you say you're not sending this to the server? Can you add a logging interceptor and post the logs here? In the end, it can be that the server has a bug and rejects the update, but still returns success.